# discord.py mute command runs but does not mute user with mod perms

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am building a bot with discord.py. I have a mute command which works fine. But when I try to mute a member who has mod/admin powers and/or their role is higher than the bot, the command runs but the user does not get muted. It would be helpful if you could also tell how to handle this. The error is :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ProgrammingAndCoding/TomAndJerry/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ProgrammingAndCoding/TomAndJerry/main.py", line 94, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ProgrammingAndCoding/TomAndJerry/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ProgrammingAndCoding/TomAndJerry/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/ProgrammingAndCoding/TomAndJerry/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Here is my code :-

```
@client.command(description="Mutes the specified user.")
@commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
@commands.cooldown(2,5, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted", description=f"{member.mention} was muted ", color=ctx.author.color)
    embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
    await member.send(f" You have been muted in: {guild.name} Reason: {reason}")
```

Edit :- I added

```
elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
    await ctx.send("That user is Mod/Admin. I can't do that! If that is not the case, please place my role above the role the person has to be muted!")
```

So now, the embed of the mute command is also sent along with "That user is Mod/Admin"

Comment: Please post the **whole** traceback. *PS: The error doesn't mean that the user who used the command doesn't have necessary permissions/roles, but that the bot doesn't have the needed permissions.*

Comment: Yes I understood that. I have edited the question, it now includes the whole traceback

Comment: @ChaoticNebula Łukasz already gave an answer to the traceback: "*that the bot doesn't have the needed permissions.*"

Comment: Yeah I got that but the embed of the mute command is also sent along with "That user is Mod/Admin"

Comment: Make it `@mute.error` and put it under the command, then use `if [....]`